# Dropbox link to www

Tags: 13.04, permissions, apache2, dropbox

I have apache installed on my Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit.
I want to link a folder named `html` from the `dropbox`, to the `www` folder.
I pressed right-click on the `html` folder, and clicked **make link**, and I cut the linked folder and pasted it in `www`, and now when I open the web pages inside the `html` folder from the web browser, it says:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /html/new kora/ on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.243 Port 80
```

although I `chmod -R 777` the linked folder, and to the `html folder in dropbox` and it didn't work. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am assuming that you have your current Apache Installation pointing to the `/var/www` folder on your server. Which can be reached in a browser via localhost and it shows the "It works!" message. If so, I think your best chance will be to point to the Public folder of your Dropbox, in which you can "host" html webpages (Won't work for PHP).

The process is easy, first of all, let's include everything inside a Folder in the Public Folder of your Dropbox. See the next screenshot in which I have made an html folder in which I have dropped several html files and their respective resource folders (images, fonts, javascript, etc.)

[image]

Now, let's choose an html file in which we'll right click, choose "Dropbox" then "Copy Public Link". As shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

Now, let's create an html file inside of `/var/www` with `gksudo gedit clock.html` (or any file name you may wish to use), then let's insert the next portion of code inside the file:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="re" content="0; url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16481702/html/clock3D.html">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Please wait. You are being redirected...</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Replace the URL with the appropriate link. Save the document and invoke it in your web browser via localhost/clock.html which will result in a redirection to the webpage hosted in Dropbox as we can see in the next screenshot (please see the address bar).

[image]

I hope this help you and maybe this is what you wish to do but if not please let us know what are you attempting in order to change this answer with the proper support for your needs.

Good luck!